# How to load custom cell magic from a relative directory (in Jupyter notebook)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a custom cell magic which I need to load from a relative path. I can do so when the module directory is in the same place as the notebook. However, it doesn't work when I have a more complex directory structure.

It works if the directory structure is this:

```
test_custom_magic\
    |-custom_magic_code\
        |-__init__.py
        |-etcetc.py
    |-test_notebook.ipy
```

In this scenario, I just do a `%reload_ext custom_magic_code` and my code works.

However, now that I'm done writing and testing the code, I'm trying to use it in a more complex directory:

```
important_project\
    |-notebooks\
        |-do_something_important.ipy
        |-do_something_else_important.ipy
    |-custom_magic_code\
        |-__init__.py
        |-etcetc.py
```

In `do_something_important.ipy`, I can't just `%reload_ext custom_magic_code`. I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

If I try `%reload_ext ../custom_magic_code` (or some other nested directory level), I get this error:
`TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '../custom_magic_code'`

How can I solve this problem?
Please note that my custom magic code is good enough for me to run locally. I'm not quite ready to package it and install via pip/conda/nbextension just yet (and I'm trying to avoid learning that anyway, until I can get my current code working).

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using the following code to include relevant directory among the paths python checks to find libraries:

```py
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('../..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

Seems to work!